# SAS date convert from numeric to character

Tags: sas

I have a SAS variable(a table column) which has a Number data type and a format YYMMDD10.
It has a value like :04/20/2019

I want to convert it to a string like:20190420.
So I do:

```
new_date= Put( trim(orig_date), mmddyy10.);
```

I get:`The format $MMDDYY was not found or could not be loaded.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main mistake is adding the unneeded TRIM() function.

You cannot use TRIM() function on a numeric variable.  Well you can, but that just means SAS will automatically convert the number into a string using the BEST12. format.  Once you have converted the data to a character string then you can no longer use the numeric MMDDYY format with the value. So SAS assumes you just left the $ off the front of your character format name. However it can't find such a character format so you get the error message.

To make sure the result has slash instead of some other delimiter you can use the MMDDYYS format.

```
new_date= Put( orig_date , mmddyys10.);
```